# Use PDF Form XObjects with Cairo's PDF surface?

Tags: pdf, cairo

I'd like to use Cairo to generate a multi-page PDF document where each page shares a common template. Is it possible to use PDF Form XObjects from Cairo so each page will share the same template, only adding the customizations to the page?

I've tried using [`Context.set_source_surface`](http://cairographics.org/documentation/pycairo/2/reference/context.html#cairo.Context.set_source_surface), but it seems to rasterize the surface before painting:

[image: example using set_source_surface]

```
import cairo

template_sfc = cairo.PDFSurface("/tmp/template.pdf", 600, 600)
template_ctx = cairo.Context(template_sfc)
template_ctx.move_to(20, 20)
template_ctx.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 0)
template_ctx.show_text("HELLO")
template_ctx.fill()

sfc = cairo.PDFSurface("/tmp/actual.pdf", 612, 792)
ctx = cairo.Context(sfc)
ctx.set_source_surface(template_sfc)
ctx.paint()
sfc.finish()
```

Comment: After much more looking, I haven't found a solution. At the moment, it looks like the best option for my use case is to use Cairo to render the PDFs, then PyPDF2 to merge them together.

Answer (score 1):

Use the recording surface instead of a PDF surface for your template. Also, the template_ctx.fill() line is not required.